# renaming a group of files

Tags: bash, xargs, mv

I want to rename all files with this pattern `-512-` to `-256-` in a folder?
How can I do that with mv? I know I have to use `xargs` and pipe it to `find` but don't know how to tell xargs

```
find . -name *-512-*
```

and

```
xargs mv ?????
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for i in *-512-*; do mv "$i" "${i/-512-/-256-}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize you asked about `mv` but this seems more like a job for `rename` imo:

```
rename 's/-512-/-256-/' *-512-*
```

Comment: you should also mention that one needs some form of `perl` installed to use this `rename` script.